# PHP Variables truncated when submitting form

Tags: php, variables, truncation

Whenever I submit my form only the first character is sent between the php class and the script handling the submission. Other characters of both $_post and variables are lost.

For example if I submit Nigeria as country in the country dropdown menu, it will only pick the N in Nigeria. and the Class methods only return the first character of whatever it was supposed to return.

This is the code for the script handling the form submission

```
<?php
include('../modules/connection.php');
include('../modules/signup.php');

$signUpHandler = new Signup();
$sub = 0;

if (isset($_POST['sign_up']) == 1) {
    $sub = 1;
    $signed = $signUpHandler->validateSignUp($_POST['fulname'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['phone'],
        $_POST['address'], $_POST['city'], $_POST['state'], $_POST['country'], $_POST['biz_type'], $_POST['biz_name'],
        $_POST['mailer_use'], $_POST['website'], $_POST['password']);
}
?>

<?php if ($sub == 1) {
    echo @$signed['regReport'];
} else { ?>
    <small class="small alert alert-info">All fields with asterik (*) are required</small><?php } ?>
<br>
<h3>Personal &amp; Contact Detail</h3>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="signup">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="fulname" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Fulname* (Lastname Firstname)" required>
        <?php echo @$signed['fulname']; ?>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="email" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email*" required>
        <?php echo @$signed['email']; ?>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="phone" class="form-control" type="tel" placeholder="Phone*" required>
        <?php echo @$signed['phone']; ?>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="address" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Address*" required border="1">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="city" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="City*" required border="1">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="state" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="State*" required border="1">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select name="country" id="country" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
            <option value="<?php echo $data['nwcountry']; ?>"
                    selected="selected"><?php echo $data['nwcountry']; ?></option>
            <option value="Afghanistan" title="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="Åland Islands" title="Åland Islands">Åland Islands</option>
            <option value="Albania" title="Albania">Albania</option>
            <option value="Algeria" title="Algeria">Algeria</option>
            <option value="American Samoa" title="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
            <option value="Andorra" title="Andorra">Andorra</option>
            <option value="Angola" title="Angola">Angola</option>
            <option value="Anguilla" title="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
            <option value="Antarctica" title="Antarctica">Antarctica</option>
            <option value="Antigua and Barbuda" title="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
            <option value="Argentina" title="Argentina">Argentina</option>
            <option value="Armenia" title="Armenia">Armenia</option>
            <option value="Aruba" title="Aruba">Aruba</option>
            <option value="Australia" title="Australia">Australia</option>
            <option value="Austria" title="Austria">Austria</option>
            <option value="Azerbaijan" title="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
            <option value="Bahamas" title="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
            <option value="Bahrain" title="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
            <option value="Bangladesh" title="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
            <option value="Barbados" title="Barbados">Barbados</option>
            <option value="Belarus" title="Belarus">Belarus</option>
            <option value="Belgium" title="Belgium">Belgium</option>
            <option value="Belize" title="Belize">Belize</option>
            <option value="Benin" title="Benin">Benin</option>
            <option value="Bermuda" title="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
            <option value="Bhutan" title="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
            <option value="Bolivia, Plurinational State of" title="Bolivia, Plurinational State of">Bolivia,
                Plurinational State of
            </option>
            <option value="Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba" title="Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba">Bonaire, Sint
                Eustatius and Saba
            </option>
            <option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina" title="Bosnia and Herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
            <option value="Botswana" title="Botswana">Botswana</option>
            <option value="Bouvet Island" title="Bouvet Island">Bouvet Island</option>
            <option value="Brazil" title="Brazil">Brazil</option>
            <option value="British Indian Ocean Territory" title="British Indian Ocean Territory">British Indian Ocean
                Territory
            </option>
            <option value="Brunei Darussalam" title="Brunei Darussalam">Brunei Darussalam</option>
            <option value="Bulgaria" title="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
            <option value="Martinique" title="Martinique">Martinique</option>
            <option value="Mauritania" title="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
            <option value="Mauritius" title="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
            <option value="Mayotte" title="Mayotte">Mayotte</option>
            <option value="Mexico" title="Mexico">Mexico</option>
            <option value="Micronesia, Federated States of" title="Micronesia, Federated States of">Micronesia,
                Federated States of
            </option>
            <option value="Moldova, Republic of" title="Moldova, Republic of">Moldova, Republic of</option>
            <option value="Monaco" title="Monaco">Monaco</option>
            <option value="Mongolia" title="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
            <option value="Montenegro" title="Montenegro">Montenegro</option>
            <option value="Montserrat" title="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
            <option value="Morocco" title="Morocco">Morocco</option>
            <option value="Mozambique" title="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
            <option value="Myanmar" title="Myanmar">Myanmar</option>
            <option value="Namibia" title="Namibia">Namibia</option>
            <option value="Nauru" title="Nauru">Nauru</option>
            <option value="Nepal" title="Nepal">Nepal</option>
            <option value="Netherlands" title="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
            <option value="New Caledonia" title="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option>
            <option value="New Zealand" title="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
            <option value="Nicaragua" title="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
            <option value="Niger" title="Niger">Niger</option>
            <option value="Nigeria" title="Nigeria" selected="selected">Nigeria</option>
            <option value="Niue" title="Niue">Niue</option>
            <option value="Norfolk Island" title="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island</option>
            <option value="Northern Mariana Islands" title="Northern Mariana Islands">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
            <option value="Norway" title="Norway">Norway</option>
            <option value="Oman" title="Oman">Oman</option>
            <option value="Pakistan" title="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
            <option value="Palau" title="Palau">Palau</option>
            <option value="Palestinian Territory, Occupied" title="Palestinian Territory, Occupied">Palestinian
                Territory, Occupied
            </option>
            <option value="Panama" title="Panama">Panama</option>
            <option value="Papua New Guinea" title="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
            <option value="Paraguay" title="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
            <option value="Peru" title="Peru">Peru</option>
            <option value="Philippines" title="Philippines">Philippines</option>
            <option value="Pitcairn" title="Pitcairn">Pitcairn</option>
            <option value="Poland" title="Poland">Poland</option>
            <option value="Portugal" title="Portugal">Portugal</option>
            <option value="Puerto Rico" title="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
            <option value="Qatar" title="Qatar">Qatar</option>
            <option value="Réunion" title="Réunion">Réunion</option>
            <option value="Romania" title="Romania">Romania</option>
            <option value="Russian Federation" title="Russian Federation">Russian Federation</option>
            <option value="Rwanda" title="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
            <option value="Saint Barthélemy" title="Saint Barthélemy">Saint Barthélemy</option>
            <option value="Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha"
                    title="Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha">Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha
            </option>
            <option value="Saint Kitts and Nevis" title="Saint Kitts and Nevis">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
            <option value="Saint Lucia" title="Saint Lucia">Saint Lucia</option>
            <option value="Saint Martin (French part)" title="Saint Martin (French part)">Saint Martin (French part)
            </option>
            <option value="Saint Pierre and Miquelon" title="Saint Pierre and Miquelon">Saint Pierre and Miquelon
            </option>
            <option value="Saint Vincent and the Grenadines" title="Saint Vincent and the Grenadines">Saint Vincent and
                the Grenadines
            </option>
            <option value="Samoa" title="Samoa">Samoa</option>
            <option value="San Marino" title="San Marino">San Marino</option>
            <option value="Sao Tome and Principe" title="Sao Tome and Principe">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
            <option value="Saudi Arabia" title="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
            <option value="Senegal" title="Senegal">Senegal</option>
            <option value="Serbia" title="Serbia">Serbia</option>
            <option value="Seychelles" title="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>
            <option value="Sierra Leone" title="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option>
            <option value="Singapore" title="Singapore">Singapore</option>
            <option value="Sint Maarten (Dutch part)" title="Sint Maarten (Dutch part)">Sint Maarten (Dutch part)
            </option>
            <option value="Slovakia" title="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
            <option value="Slovenia" title="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
            <option value="Solomon Islands" title="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
            <option value="Somalia" title="Somalia">Somalia</option>
            <option value="South Africa" title="South Africa">South Africa</option>
            <option value="South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands"
                    title="South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands">South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands
            </option>
            <option value="South Sudan" title="South Sudan">South Sudan</option>
            <option value="Spain" title="Spain">Spain</option>
            <option value="Sri Lanka" title="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
            <option value="Sudan" title="Sudan">Sudan</option>
            <option value="Suriname" title="Suriname">Suriname</option>
            <option value="Svalbard and Jan Mayen" title="Svalbard and Jan Mayen">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option>
            <option value="Swaziland" title="Swaziland">Swaziland</option>
            <option value="Sweden" title="Sweden">Sweden</option>
            <option value="Switzerland" title="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
            <option value="Syrian Arab Republic" title="Syrian Arab Republic">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
            <option value="Taiwan, Province of China" title="Taiwan, Province of China">Taiwan, Province of China
            </option>
            <option value="Tajikistan" title="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>
            <option value="Tanzania, United Republic of" title="Tanzania, United Republic of">Tanzania, United Republic
                of
            </option>
            <option value="Thailand" title="Thailand">Thailand</option>
            <option value="Timor-Leste" title="Timor-Leste">Timor-Leste</option>
            <option value="Togo" title="Togo">Togo</option>
            <option value="Tokelau" title="Tokelau">Tokelau</option>
            <option value="Tonga" title="Tonga">Tonga</option>
            <option value="Trinidad and Tobago" title="Trinidad and Tobago">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
            <option value="Tunisia" title="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
            <option value="Turkey" title="Turkey">Turkey</option>
            <option value="Turkmenistan" title="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
            <option value="Turks and Caicos Islands" title="Turks and Caicos Islands">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
            <option value="Tuvalu" title="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>
            <option value="Uganda" title="Uganda">Uganda</option>
            <option value="Ukraine" title="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
            <option value="United Arab Emirates" title="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option>
            <option value="United Kingdom" title="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
            <option value="United States" title="United States">United States</option>
            <option value="United States Minor Outlying Islands" title="United States Minor Outlying Islands">United
                States Minor Outlying Islands
            </option>
            <option value="Uruguay" title="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
            <option value="Uzbekistan" title="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
            <option value="Vanuatu" title="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
            <option value="Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of" title="Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of">Venezuela,
                Bolivarian Republic of
            </option>
            <option value="Viet Nam" title="Viet Nam">Viet Nam</option>
            <option value="Virgin Islands, British" title="Virgin Islands, British">Virgin Islands, British</option>
            <option value="Virgin Islands, U.S." title="Virgin Islands, U.S.">Virgin Islands, U.S.</option>
            <option value="Wallis and Futuna" title="Wallis and Futuna">Wallis and Futuna</option>
            <option value="Western Sahara" title="Western Sahara">Western Sahara</option>
            <option value="Yemen" title="Yemen">Yemen</option>
            <option value="Zambia" title="Zambia">Zambia</option>
            <option value="Zimbabwe" title="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <h4>Login Details</h4>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="username" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username*" required border="1" max="16"
               min="6"><?php if ($sub == 1) {
            echo @$signed['username'];
        } else { ?>
            <small class="small text-info">6-16 characters of upper, lower alphabets &amp; numbers or combinations
            </small><?php } ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password*" required border="1">
    </div>
    <hr>
    <h4>Business Detail</h4>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="biz_name" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Business Name*" required border="1">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="biz_type" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Business Type*" required border="1">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select name="mailer_use" class="form-control">
            <option selected value="">What do you need MBC MailBlast for?</option>
            <option value="Send Newsletter">Send Newsletter</option>
            <option value="Market Products/Services">Market Products/Services</option>
            <option value="Send Trasactional Emails">Send Transactional emails</option>
            <option value="Send Routine Emails">Send Routine/Reminders</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="website" class="form-control" type="url" placeholder="Business Website (Ex. http://website.com)"
               border="1"><?php echo @$signed['website']; ?>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-block btn-success" type="submit" name="sign_up" value="sign up"><i
                    class="fa fa-login"></i> Sign Up
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Below is the PHP class script in another file

```
<?php

class Signup extends Connection
{
    private $fulname, $email, $phone, $address, $city, $state, $country, $bizType, $bizName, $mailerUse, $biz_website, $username, $password, $con;
    private $err = array();

    public function validateSignUp(
        $fulname,
        $username,
        $email,
        $phone,
        $address,
        $city,
        $state,
        $country,
        $bizType,
        $bizName,
        $mailerUse,
        $biz_website,
        $password
    ) {

        $this->con = Connection::connect();

        $this->fulname = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->con, trim(stripslashes(strip_tags(ucfirst($fulname)))));
        $this->email = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->con, trim(stripslashes(strip_tags($email))));
        $this->username = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->con, trim(stripslashes(strip_tags($username))));
        $this->phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->con, trim(stripslashes(strip_tags($phone))));
        $this->address = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->con, trim(stripslashes(strip_tags(ucfirst($address)))));
        $this->city = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->con, trim(stripslashes(strip_tags(ucfirst($city)))));
        $this->state = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->con, trim(stripslashes(strip_tags(ucfirst($state)))));
        $this->country = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->con, trim(stripslashes(strip_tags(ucfirst($country)))));
        $this->bizType = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->con, trim(stripslashes(strip_tags(ucfirst($bizType)))));
        $this->bizName = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->con, trim(stripslashes(strip_tags(ucfirst($bizName)))));
        $this->mailerUse = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->con, trim(stripslashes(strip_tags($mailerUse))));
        $this->biz_website = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->con,
            trim(stripslashes(strip_tags(strtolower($biz_website)))));
        $this->password = hash("SHA512", $password);

        $this->err['count'] = 0;

        if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z\s.\-]+$/", $this->fulname)) {
            $this->err['fulname'] = '<p class="small alert alert-danger">Name contains invalid characters, please check entry again!</p>';
            $this->err['count']++;
        }
        if (!filter_var($this->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $this->err['email'] = '<p class="alert alert-danger small">Invalid Email address please, verify!</p>';
            $this->err['count']++;
        }
        if (!ctype_digit($this->phone)) {
            $this->err['phone'] = '<p class="alert alert-danger small">Invalid phone number supplied! Only digits are accepted</p>';
            $this->err['count']++;
        }
        if (strlen($this->phone) != 11 && $this->country == 'Nigeria') {
            $this->err['phone'] = '<p class="alert alert-danger small">Phone number for Nigerian subscriber must be 11 digits!</p>';
            $this->err['count']++;
        }
        if (!filter_var($this->biz_website, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) && $this->biz_website != "") {
            $this->err['website'] = '<p class="alert alert-danger small">Invalid website address submitted! Please, enter a valid website address example http://website.com</p>';
            $this->err['count']++;
        }
        if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z]||[A-Za-z][0-9]$/", $this->username)) {
            $this->err['username'] = '<p class="alert alert-danger small">Username can only have Uppercase, lowercase, digits or a mixture!</p>';
            $this->err['count']++;
        }
        if (strlen($this->username) < 6 || strlen($this->username) > 16) {
            $this->err['username'] = '<p class="alert alert-danger small">Username should have between 6 to 16 characters</p>';
            $this->err['count']++;
        }
        if ($this->err['count'] == 0) {
            $this->err['regReport'] = $this->regUser();
            return $this->err['regReport'];
        } else {
            $this->err['regReport'] = '<div class="alert alert-danger">One or more field submitted contains invalid data. Correct and re-submit to continue</div>';
            return $this->err;
        }
    }

    private function regUser()
    {
        $dateReg = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        $regUser = mysqli_query($this->con,
            "INSERT INTO `mailer-account`(`email`,`username`,`password`,`phone`,`address`,`city`,`state`,`country`,`business_name`,`business_type`,`mailer-use`,`business_website`,`date_reg`) VALUES('$this->email','$this->username','$this->password','$this->phone','$this->address','$this->city','$this->state','$this->country','$this->bizName','$this->bizType','$this->mailerUse','$this->biz_website','$dateReg')");

        if (mysqli_affected_rows($this->con) == 1) {
            header("Location:../confirmation?suc=" . base64_encode("Registration Successful! A confirmation email has been sent to $this->email. Check email to activate your account!"));
        } else {
            return '<div class="alert alert-danger">Unable to complete registration at the moment! Err: SGN79</div>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: i dont see any code for actually accessing `$_POST`

Comment: Need to see where you're accessing $_POST.  If you're only getting the first character you might be treating a string like an array, like `$country = 'Nigeria'; echo $country[0];`

Comment: How are you verifying the problem? Are you debugging the PHP? Displaying the variables somehow (`var_dump()` / `print_r()`)? Looking in the database? If you're only seeing the issue in the DB, what are your column data types?

Comment: I observed that the $_POST values are displaying right before they are passed to the object of the class Signup. The problem just seems to be between passing the arguments and receiving the returned results

Answer (score 0):

After trying out other solutions found via online forums and articles. I later found a solution to the problem.

```
if(isset($_POST['sign_up'])==1){

            $signUpHandler = new Signup($_POST);

            $sub=1;
            $signed = $signUpHandler->validateSignUp();
        }
```

The class changed to:

```
<?php
    class Signup extends Connection{

            private $_data = array(), $_con;
            private $_err = array();


            //Class constructor for Signing up
            public function __construct($data = array()){
                    $this->_con = Connection::connect();

                    $this->_data['fulname'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->_con, trim(stripslashes(strip_tags(ucfirst($data['fulname'])))));
                    $this->_data['email'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->_con, trim(stripslashes(strip_tags($data['email']))));
                    $this->_data['username'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->_con, trim(stripslashes(strip_tags($data['username']))));
                    $this->_data['phone'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->_con, trim(stripslashes(strip_tags($data['phone']))));
                    $this->_data['address'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->_con, trim(stripslashes(strip_tags(ucfirst($data['address'])))));
                    $this->_data['city'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->_con, trim(stripslashes(strip_tags(ucfirst($data['city'])))));
                    $this->_data['state'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->_con, trim(stripslashes(strip_tags(ucfirst($data['state'])))));
                    $this->_data['country'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->_con, trim(stripslashes(strip_tags(ucfirst($data['country'])))));
                    $this->_data['bizType'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->_con, trim(stripslashes(strip_tags(ucfirst($data['biz_type'])))));
                    $this->_data['bizName'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->_con, trim(stripslashes(strip_tags(ucfirst($data['biz_name'])))));
                    $this->_data['mailerUse'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->_con, trim(stripslashes(strip_tags($data['mailer_use']))));
                    $this->_data['biz_website'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->_con, trim(stripslashes(strip_tags(strtolower($data['website'])))));
                    $this->_data['password'] = hash("SHA512",$data['password']);
                }


            //Validate User details
            public function validateSignUp(){

                    $this->_err['count']=0;

                    if(!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z\s.\-]+$/",$this->_data['fulname'])){
                            $this->_err['fulname'] = '<p class="small alert alert-danger">Name contains invalid characters, please check entry again!</p>';
                            $this->_err['count']++;
                        }
                    if(!filter_var($this->_data['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                            $this->_err['email']='<p class="alert alert-danger small">Invalid Email address please, verify!</p>';
                            $this->_err['count']++;
                        }

                    if(!ctype_digit($this->_data['phone'])){
                            $this->_err['phone']='<p class="alert alert-danger small">Invalid phone number supplied! Only digits are accepted</p>';
                            $this->_err['count']++;
                        }
                    if(strlen($this->_data['phone'])!=11 && $this->_data['country']=='Nigeria'){
                            $this->_err['phone']='<p class="alert alert-danger small">Phone number for Nigerian subscriber must be 11 digits!</p>';
                            $this->_err['count']++;
                        }
                    if(!filter_var($this->_data['biz_website'],FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) && $this->_data['biz_website']!=""){
                            $this->_err['website']='<p class="alert alert-danger small">Invalid website address submitted! Please, enter a valid website address example http://website.com</p>';
                            $this->_err['count']++;
                        }
                    if(!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z]||[A-Za-z][0-9]$/",$this->_data['username'])){

                            $this->_err['username']='<p class="alert alert-danger small">Username can only have Uppercase, lowercase, digits or a mixture!</p>';
                            $this->_err['count']++;     
                        }

                    if(strlen($this->_data['username'])<6 || strlen($this->_data['username'])>16){
                            $this->_err['username']='<p class="alert alert-danger small">Username should have between 6 to 16 characters</p>';
                            $this->_err['count']++;
                        }


                        if($this->_err['count']==0){

                                $this->_err['regReport'] = $this->regUser();

                                return $this->_err;

                            }else{
                                    $this->_err['regReport'] = '<div class="alert alert-danger">One or more field submitted contains invalid data. Correct and re-submit to continue</div>';
                                    return $this->_err;
                                }

                }


                private function regUser(){

                        $dateReg = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

                        $regUser = mysqli_query($this->_con, "INSERT INTO `mailer-account`(`email`,`username`,`password`,`phone`,`address`,`city`,`state`,`country`,`business_name`,`business_type`,`mailer_use`,`business_website`,`date_reg`) VALUES('{$this->_data['email']}','{$this->_data['username']}','{$this->_data['password']}','{$this->_data['phone']}','{$this->_data['address']}','{$this->_data['city']}','{$this->_data['state']}','{$this->_data['country']}','{$this->_data['bizName']}','{$this->_data['bizType']}','{$this->_data['mailerUse']}','{$this->_data['biz_website']}','$dateReg')");

                        if(mysqli_affected_rows($this->_con)==1){
                                header("Location:../confirmation?suc=".base64_encode("Registration Successful! A confirmation email has been sent to ".$this->_data['email'].". Check email to activate your account!"));
                            }else{
                                    return '<div class="alert alert-danger">Unable to complete registration at the moment! Err: SGN84</div>';
                                }

                    }
        }
?>
```